# Package/Path/import logic issue

Tags: java, linux, ant, debian

I am having an issue for a homework project where we are creating a MVC like package of classes. Using a Debian 9.x.x virtual box, we are to use an ant file to build/compile/execute.

I am including a screenshot of both the overall directory structure mandated, as well as the source directory structure mandated.

We are specifically to have a source files in the structure:

[image]

With that in mind, we are supposed to package the source files as ser321.assign3.kajeffr1.client. I have tried this as relative (which I didn't think made sense since the local path doesn't include what is desired in the class package path), and as absolute. However, my classes don't seem to recognize each other. I get the following error.

[image]

It is my understanding that the package paths shouldn't really matter because it can compile to where it wants. I tried imports from the other classes and it didn't seem to help, not to mention they are all in the same directory so I don't know why Message seems to be invisible to the other classes. I am including my build.xml and beginning of the source files since it seems like my error is in packaging/importing, but if the rest of the code is needed I can provide that as well.

build.xml:

```
    <project name="Ser321 Spring 2019 Assign2" default="targets" basedir=".">
    <!-- set global properties for this build -->

    <property name="src" value="./src" />
    <property name="build" value="./classes" />
    <property name="docs" value="./docs" />
    <property name="lib" value="./lib" />
    <property name="userId" value="kajeffr1" />
    <property name="parentDir" value="${user.dir}${file.separator}" />
    <path id="compile.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${build}/"/>
    <fileset dir="${lib}">
    <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    </path>
    <target name="targets">
       <echo message="targets are clean, prepare, compile, and execute. "/>
    </target>

    <target name="prepare">
    <!-- Create the time stamp -->
    <tstamp/>
    <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
    <echo message="home defined as: ${home}" />
    <mkdir dir="${build}" />
    </target>
    <target name="compile" depends="prepare"
    description="Compile Java sources">
    <javac srcdir="${src}/client"
    includeantruntime="false"
    destdir="${build}">
    <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
    </javac>
    </target>
    <target name="execute" depends="compile"
    description="execute the execute mail client">
    <java classname="ser321.assign2.kajeffr1.client.MessageController"
    fork="yes">
    <arg value="kajeffr1"/> 
    <arg value="localhost:8080"/> 
    <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
    </java>
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
    <!-- Delete the ${build} and ${docs} directory trees -->
    <delete dir="${build}" />
    </target>
    </project>
```

Message.java:

```
        package ser321.assign2.kajeffr1.client;

        import java.io.Serializable;
        import org.json.JSONObject;

        public class Message implements Serializable { ... }
```

MessageLibary.java:

```
    package ser321.assign2.kajeffr1.src.client;

    public interface MessageLibrary { ... }
```

MessageLibraryImpl.java:

```
    package ser321.assign2.kajeffr1.src.client;

    import org.json.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class MessageLibraryImpl implements Serializable, MessageLibrary { ... }
```

MessageController.java:

```
    package ser321.assign2.kajeffr1.src.client;

    //other java imports

    public class MessageController extends MessageGui //MessageGUI is provided in jar files { ... }
```

The ant file is building the "classes" file and then failing to compile anything into it.

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Also see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/608639)

Answer (score 0):

I was just missing the ".src." in my Message.java. I can't believe how many times I must have missed that.